# Is there a way to start a hangout from another app with openURL: on the Google+ app for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, google-plus, openurl

I'm building an app that needs to start a video conference from an iPhone.
They way i've implemented it is to first check if Skype is installed, if it is, i start video conferencing with skype.
If not, im checking if the Google+ app installed.  And if it is i want to open that app with a Google+ username to start a hangout with the user.

an example would be:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:"googleplus://username@gmail.com"]
```

Do you know if this is possible, and whats the correct identifier to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to start a Google+ Hangout with only an API call.  However, there is a Google+ Hangouts Button that will start one.

https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button